# Qtable add q-btn-dropdown

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to add a dropdown button to my Qtable.
Here is the solution that I want to achieve:

[image]

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#example--body-cell-name-slot or body slot to achieve this.

For dropdown - https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select

Comment: https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/BaVQBRv